# How to make input field disable based on another input field

Tags: html, angular, typescript

How to make "passed out year" field disable if the degree is not typed. May I know can we achieve it in html without .ts file use.

```html
  <div>  Degree:                    
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="degree" #degree/></div>

<div>
Passed Out Year
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="passedYear"/></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this `[disabled]="!formName.controls['degree'].value"` in case you want any value, or this `[disabled]="!formName.controls['degree'].valid"` in case you want passedyear to be entered correctly.

However, if you need to implement more complex checks you may want to add custom validators.

Comment: you could even shorten it to degree.value i think because he has the #degree

Comment: sure, I also made a mistake, in case you want to disable 'passedYear' input, you have to check 'degree'

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly how you are planning to use this, but you may not need to use Angular Forms if you're doing something simple. In that case you can accomplish what you need by just using ngModel like this

```
<div> Degree:
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="degree" />
</div>

<div>
    Passed Out Year
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [disabled]="!degree" />
</div>
```